# How to process a dataframe row by row, passing the columns as args to a function, *as a single call to function*

Tags: r

Still quite new to R.  Its quite possible my question is due to gaps in my thinking about this problem, but after few hours of googling, I'm still stuck.

**The problem:**

- I have a dataframe(tibble) that contains 6 rows, and 3 columns.
- The columns are Filename, Metadata1, Metadata2.
- I want to call a function for each row, as follows:
  function(Filename, Metadata1, Metadata2).

In other languages, this would be a simple `for` loop, but I am completely stuck how to do this in R, both looking at base, and tidyverse ways to do this.  All the answers I've come across are variations of calling the function on every element in the dataframe or matrix, whereas I want to effectively pass the whole row to the function, as individual args.

Its probably blindly obvious, but I would really appreciate some guidance.

*EDIT:*

I ran across `mapply`, and it seems to do the job I need, but I have no idea if this is the only or best method.  This what I'm working with currently:

```
testfunc <- function(a,b,c){
  str(a)
  str(b)
  str(c)
}

discard <- mapply(testfunc, a=files_sorted$file, b=files_sorted$AppID, c=files_sorted$server)
```

Comment: Since you're using a tibble, the tidyverse solution would include the `purrr` package somehow. Can't remember the implementation though.

Comment: I don't see why you can't use a `for` loop here. They get an unfair bad wrap but in some cases they are exactly what you need. Otherwise the `mapply` is a fine choice just using base R or you could use `lmap` from `purrr`. It would be even better if you made sure your `testfunc` function was properly vectorized so you didn't even have to worry about looping or special functions. What is "best" really depends on what that function does exactly. Seems like you might just be overcomplicating this.

Answer (score 0):

Moments after I posted the last edit to my question, I hit the exact issue that @mrflick mentioned where my function was not vectorised.

In the end, I did end up using a for loop, this is what I settled on:

```
overall_data <- tibble()

for(a in transpose(files_sorted)){
  df <- processFile(file=a[1]$list_files, srv=a[2]$server, tap=a[3]$AppID )
  #view(df)
  overall_data <- bind_rows(overall_data, df)
}
```

files_sorted:

[image: Content of files_storted tibble]

I'm sure I'll learn better ways to tackle this in future, but leaving this here